# Show that one equation equals another (trigonometry)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, problem-solving

I'm studying for a test and when going through old exams I find this one which I'm not able to solve.

Show that

> $$a^2 = (b−c)^2 + 4bc \sin^2 \left(\frac A2\right)$$

equals

> $$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc \cos(A)$$

Hint:

> $$\cos(θ) = \frac{e^{iθ} + e^{-iθ}}2 \quad\text{and}\quad \sin(θ) = \frac{e^{iθ} - e^{-iθ}}{2i}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! it is highly recommended to show some effort. What have you tried? Hint: $\displaystyle \sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. Also, by "one equation equals another" do you mean the two equations are *equivalent*?

Comment: Well, I have tried but didn't manage to solve it. The a represents a side in an arbitrary triangle abc where A is its angle.

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2 = (b−c)^2 + 4bc \sin^2\frac{A}{2} = b^2+c^2-2bc+4bc \sin^2\frac{A}{2} = \\ = b^2+c^2-2bc(1-2\sin^2\frac{A}{2})=b^2+c^2-2bc\ cosA$$
where in the last line, the well known half-angle identity:
$$1-2\sin^2\frac{A}{2}=cosA$$
has been used.

Comment: Okay, I see. But could you solve the equality using the hints given?